# How receive JSON object via HttpClient?

Tags: android, json, jakarta-ee, request, httpclient

I use HttpClient in android to send post request:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(hostNameCollection);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString());

    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


    request.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    Log.v("HttpLogClient.logJSONObject", "wyslano JSON");
```

and I'dont know how I can receive JSON object on my Java EE servlet.

Answer (score 2):

you need to read the response body text, then parse as JSON,

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

read the body of the http post ( server-side ) by getting the a stream object on the body and then reading it.

Once youve read it , convert the bytes to chars and that will be json which you can use to build a json object like a jsonNode using 'jackson' libs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain servlets the json stream is located in the body of the HttpServletRequest : request.getReader() or request.getInputStream();

To make things easier you could use a library handling databinding for you.
Have a look at Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/.

```
YouClass object = new Genson().deserialize(request.getReader(), YourClass.class);
// or to a plain map
Map<String, Object> map = genson.deserialize(request.getReader(), Map.class);
```